# Devise - Redirected to page if account isn't confirmed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to redirect the user if their account hasn't been confirmed. So this involves two parts of the code:

1. Redirect the user after they first create the account
2. Redirect them if they try to sign in before confirming the account

I need help with the second.

The first I was able to do by putting in `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)` in my custom RegistrationsController. I've tried to do the same for a SessionsController, but it didn't work. What do I need to over write in order to properly redirect the user if they haven't confirmed the account yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may have to create a custom warden strategy and check if the account needs confirmation. Something of this sorts:

```
# config/initializers/my_strategy.rb
Warden::Strategies.add(:my_strategy) do 
  def valid? 
    true
  end 

  def authenticate! 
    u = User.find_for_authentication(:email => params[:email])
    if u.nil? || !u.valid_password?(params[:password])
      fail(:invalid)
    elsif !u.confirmed?
      fail!("Account needs confirmation.")
      redirect!("your_root_url")
    end
  else
    success!(u)
  end    
end

#config/initializers/devise.rb
config.warden do |manager|  
  manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :my_strategy
end
```

This assumes the username and password are passed in the request as params. You can look at the [database_authenticable strategy](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/database_authenticatable.rb) for an example of how Devise deals with sign-in authentication by default.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you know when app/views/devise/confirmations/new.html.erb used? Seems like this should be default functionality of devise, right?

Comment: It should be used whenever you click on the "resend confirmation" link, assuming you have `:confirmable` in your model.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction with Warden strategies. Not sure I would have found out about that.

Comment: Is there no more easy way of doing this? This seems quite cybersome and could break on updates. just redirecting to a certain path instead of showing the message "you have to confirm your account before login " is my goal

Comment: Also no longer works on 2.2.2 any thoughts on how to fix it? thank you for posting this