# redirect to a certain page instead of :notice when non-confirmed user logs in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

How would one redirect a *non confirmed* user on login to a certain page instead of showing a :notice ( " you have to confirm your account " ). Using the Devise gem (latest)

This question: ( [Devise - Redirected to page if account isn't confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208492/devise-redirected-to-page-if-account-isnt-confirmed) ) provides this solution:

```
# config/initializers/my_strategy.rb
Warden::Strategies.add(:my_strategy) do 
  def valid? 
    true
  end 

  def authenticate! 
    u = User.find_for_authentication(:email => params[:email])
    if u.nil? || !u.valid_password?(params[:password])
      fail(:invalid)
    elsif !u.confirmed?
      fail!("Account needs confirmation.")
      redirect!("your_root_url")
    end
  else
    success!(u)
  end    
end

#config/initializers/devise.rb
config.warden do |manager|  
  manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :my_strategy
end
```

which does not work.

Comment: Probably duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208492/devise-redirected-to-page-if-account-isnt-confirmed

Comment: @gg_s: Im using the latest Devise indeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I fixed it like in example below
BUT I would like to know if its possible to pass the User object ( username ) inside this method so I can redirect to /confirm/ using devise user model user.username or user.login..**

```
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
  end

  class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
    def redirect_url
        if warden_message == :unconfirmed
          "/confirm"
        else
          super
        end
      end
```

Comment: hi Rubytastic, if you want to interact with **User Object**, I believe my solution, which indeed works, is a good choice. have you tried it?

Comment: @Brian Hi, yes ive tried it in my application it does not give the expected behaviour So im now reverting back in using my warden auth method.

Comment: can you give me the error msg you got from using my solution? I  wonder why it works on my machine but yours very much :)

Comment: It just doesen't work It throws the default notice, your code really is not working sorry, the process of detecting if a user is enabled is handled *before* the create controller. Really using a warden strategy is the only way because that hooks in before the custom create code and redirects the user ( the create method is only triggered *after* a devise user is logged in, wich never hapens for non confirmed users. So although the logic is correct it wil not trigger :)

Comment: you can take a look at devise's source code: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb
as you can see, on the 2nd line, the source code **won't** authenticate **before calling `create`** (`:require_no_authentication`), and will do the authentication in the `create` method instead(on the 15th line). if a user is confirmed, I will call the original method (`super`). otherwise, I will redirect the user. anyways, according to the source code, I believe my code should work. I guess you have something else conflicts with my code :(.

Answer (score 6):

generate your own session controller to override devise's default session controller with `rails g controller sessions` (the name of this controller does not matter, you can have your own choice)

edit `config/routes.rb`

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "sessions"}
```

edit `app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb`

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
    if !@user or @user.confirmed?
      super
    else
      redirect_to YOUR_DESIRED_path
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: this seems logic but won't work. Warden is taking care of the auth before this controller method is hit in a way you can catch it off

Comment: I am very sure this works because I just created a totally new rails app to test this code before answering. As this controller overrides devise's default session controller, this customized `create` method would be called **immediately** after user click "log in". Therefore, the logic here should work fine. please give it a try, and give me the error message if you get any.

Answer (score 4):

I've had better luck overriding Devise's Controllers in my application for fine tuning, which is usually the Devise SessionsController.

As an example:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    #overriding Devise's create controller first
    super

    #check if current user is inactive
    @user = user_from_current_user
    unless @user.active?
      redirect("your_root_url")
    end
  end

end
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for sharing this suggestion sadly it doesent work on 2.2.2 and rails 3.11 Im still getting only the flash message and no redirect to the custom path not even with redirect_to "/confirm"

Comment: I think I forgot to mention that routes.rb needs to be informed of this change. Sorry about that. I believe @Brian has provided a better answer. HTH.